# Get a single value from dataSet in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I am doing a query to get Title and RespondBY from the tbl_message table, I want to decrypt the Title before I do databinding to the repeater. How can I access the title value before doing databind.

```
string MysqlStatement = "SELECT Title, RespondBy  FROM tbl_message  WHERE tbl_message.MsgID = @MsgID";

using (DataServer server = new DataServer())
{
    MySqlParameter[] param = new MySqlParameter[1];
    param[0] = new MySqlParameter("@MsgID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
    param[0].Value = MessageID;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MsgID", MessageID);
    ds = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, MysqlStatement, param);
}
rptList.DataSource = ds;
rptList.DataBind();


  <table style="width: 498px; color: #F5F5F5;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptList" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td width="15%">
                        <b>Subject</b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="60%">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Subj" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: In your code you have put an Extra "," after "RespondBy". Is the query working fine?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Probably, like following code part you can get the Title and try this coding before

```
rptList.DataSource = ds;
  rptList.DataBind();
```

The following code part can get the Title from [dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
string title = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

string title = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

I used the index instead of the title name. Personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by decrypt but if you want to modify the Title by applying some logic on it then instead of binding text with Title you can create a method which takes Title as input and returns the decrypted text. You can bind you label to this method, passing it the Title.