# Can we assign a particular dataset column value to a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data set dsProcesses which returns some rows & columns.Now i need to store into a string all the data present in one particular column[Process-ID] of this data set.Can any one of u please suggest in a detailed way.

Comment: Yes it is. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, say your dataset is ds then ds.Tables[0].Rows[X][Y] will give you the value. You can further convert this value to string, int etc. as per your needs using Convert.ToString, Convert.ToInt32 respectively.

Comment: Thanks Shashank Chaturvedi and ohlmar...its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can

```
String str = DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[RowIndex]["ColumnNameOrIndex"].ToString();
String str = DataSet.Tables["TableName"].Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

Take a look at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765548/get-a-single-value-from-dataset-in-asp-net)

Comment: yeah i'm trying now but one doubt.....actually dataset is of object type....does it assigns its values to a string

Comment: That's why we are using ToString Method. It will cast it

Comment: Hey yes...its working...but i still require some more clarification...post you soon after debugging...gimme sometime pls

Comment: yes i'm done but i need to store all the data into the string but rows[0]["columnname"] is giving only the column data present in that particular row.....

Answer (score 1):

This code will create comma delimited string with the data from that column

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dsProcesses.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            strprocessid = strprocessid + dsProcesses.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ProcessID"].ToString() + ",";
         }
        strprocessid = strprocessid.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: The following line removes the comma that associates with the string at the end.                                                        strprocessid = strprocessid.TrimEnd(',');

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
DataSet ds = //call your data
        string sMyData = string.Empty;
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            sMyData = sMyData + "," + dr["ProcessID"].ToString();
        }
```